# Should dispose() be called on the same thread if I want to make a new subscription right away?

Tags: rx-java, android-room

Have a look at the following code:

```
init {
  disposable = itemsDao.getAll()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedilers.mainThread())
    .subscribe { newItems ->
      items.clear()
      items.addAll(newItems)
      itemsProcessor.onNext(newItems)
    }
}

// ??? @MainThread ???
fun onNewItemsFetched(newItems: List<Item>) {
  disposable?.dispose()
  disposable = Completable.fromAction {
    items.clear()
    items.addAll(newItems)
    itemsProcessor.onNext(newItems)
  }
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedilers.mainThread())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .andThen(db.clearAndInsert(newItems)) // <-- a @Transaction
}
```

Upon initialization and before new items are fetched from server I'm observing them from the DB.
As soon as new items are fetched from server I want to stop observing the DB & just insert the new ones. I did this in a such kind of strange way, because I'm dealing with ~100,000 items, so the `OutOfMemoryError` may occur.

My question is: should I always subscribe and call `dispose()` on my `disposable` in the same (probably main) thread to make sure that **observing the DB is already cancelled when I'm about to insert new items**?

Comment: You can dispose on any thread you want.